# Location API on Windows 10 for Desktop applications C++

Tags: c++, windows, location, windows-10

it seems that location API is legacy(?). It does not work the GetReport(...) but works ok if you set RegisterForReport(...) The error I get is the follow

```
drivers\mobilepc\locationconvergence\api\winlegacyapi\dllapi\legacyapiimpltemplate.h(197)\LocationApi.dll!06552CA7: (caller: 06552D34) ReturnHr[PreRelease](1) tid(478) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
    [CLocationApiImplTemplate<class CLegacyPositionRequest,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_e4e915a9_8344_4f88_9326_2adc071d4ff6>::GetReportInterval(!m_fRegistered)]
SalesMan::AGW_CLASS::AGWLocationWin8::GetLocation> HR=8007139F
SalesMan::AGW_CLASS::AGWLocationWin8::GetLocation> reportInterval=0
drivers\mobilepc\locationconvergence\api\winlegacyapi\dllapi\legacyapiimpltemplate.h(158)\LocationApi.dll!06554401: (caller: 06554448) ReturnHr[PreRelease](2) tid(478) 800700E8 The pipe is being closed.
    [CLocationApiImplTemplate<class CLegacyPositionRequest,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_e4e915a9_8344_4f88_9326_2adc071d4ff6>::GetReport(m_pLatLongReport == nullptr)]
drivers\mobilepc\locationconvergence\api\winlegacyapi\dllapi\legacypositionrequest.cpp(80)\LocationApi.dll!06554469: (caller: 06552BF2) ReturnHr[PreRelease](3) tid(478) 800700E8 The pipe is being closed.
    [CLegacyPositionRequest::GetReport(__super::GetReport(ReportType, ppLocationReport))]
```

I must say here that  RequestPermissions(...) works fine and returns OK. The same application on windows 8.1 works fine.
Anyone any idea?

Thank you in advance
George

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the problem by implementing the event driven location report.
Probably Windows 10 initialize slower the location than windows 8 , since the hardware is the same. I give it a 3 seconds report interval and reports back the lat/lon

George